# Vim package Vulnerable

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, vim, neovim

is the latest `vim` package for Ubuntu 16/18 vulnerable to `modeline`?

I have two production ubuntu based servers, one has 18.04.2 LTS on it and the other one has 16.04.6 LTS on it.

Neither `apt-get upgrade` nor `apt-get dist-upgrade` showed any new releases for vim.

Latest package is 7.4 on Ubuntu 16, and 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.

Any suggestions?

src: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/bwp7q3/code_execution_vulnerability_in_vim_811365_and/

Answer (score 0):

There is no vim update package yet on distro version you mention. You can disable modeline by doing `:set modeline` once you open vim also use the `securemodeline` plugin or download and compile vim from the github repo, this bug was fixed 19 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

as a work around, just execute this command using root:

```
echo -e "set modelines=0\nset nomodeline" >> /etc/vim/vimrc
```

this would disable modeline.

**What's a modeline again?**

> A string like /* vim: set textwidth=80 tabstop=8: */ at the start or
>   end of a file that tells Vim to set particular options.